# Failed to get ansible_facts, when become: true, is set

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

The ansible playbook hangs for hours and does not give any output when i give `become: yes`. Please check the playbook below:

```
- name: Play to get the gathre facts content
  hosts: DEV1
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: print ansible_facts
    debug:
     var: ansible_facts["kernel"]
```

Output:

The playbook execution hangs and hence no output.

```
ansibleuser@debian:~/ansible_code$ ansible-playbook  playbooks/gatherfacts_playbook.yaml

PLAY [Play to get the gathre facts content] ********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
```

For the same playbook if i `remove become: yes` then it works fine:

```
- name: Play to get the gathre facts content
  hosts: DEV1
  tasks:
  - name: print ansible_facts
    debug:
     var: ansible_facts["kernel"]
```

Output:

Playbook executes and give the kernal version of host machine.

```
ansibleuser@debian:~/ansible_code$ ansible-playbook  playbooks/gatherfacts_playbook.yaml

PLAY [Play to get the gathre facts content] ********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host DEV1 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter
could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
ok: [DEV1]

TASK [print ansible_facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [DEV1] => {
    "ansible_facts[\"kernel\"]": "4.9.0-12-amd64"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
DEV1                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Please explain:**

1. Why is this happening?
2. What is the way to run playbook with `become: yes` and get the output?
3. If `become: yes` can't be used then how to run Linux headers update `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` which needs the kernel version. Below is the play which hangs as `become: yes is set`.

Example:

```
- hosts: DEV1
  become: yes
  tasks
  - name: Update linux kernel header and install build essential
    apt:
     name:
      - "linux-headers-{{ ansible_facts["kernel"] }}"
      - build-essential
```

Comment: It should work, provided the user has `sudo`/`su` access. Which user are you using? May be you need to supply the password? Try with `ansible-playbook  playbooks/gatherfacts_playbook.yaml -K`

Comment: @Seshadri C: Thanks for your reply. Got to know the use of -K. After putting -K option, i entered BECOME password. But the execution again hanged. In this scenario, the user in the host machine is added in the sudoers file. with the following details: testuser  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

Answer (score 0):

In inventory file i am using `testuser` as the user `to login to DEV1 host machine`. This user is add in the sudoers file with the permission `testuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. So i added `become_user as testuser` in the playbook and the playbook executed successfully. Below is the playbook:

```
- name: Play to get the gathre facts content
  hosts: DEV1
  become: yes
  become_user: testuser
  tasks:
  - name: print ansible_facts
    debug:
     var: ansible_facts["kernel"]
```

Output:

```
ansibleuser@debian:~/ansible_code$ ansible-playbook  playbooks/gatherfacts_playbook.yaml

PLAY [Play to get the gather facts content] ********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host DEV1 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter
could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
ok: [DEV1]

TASK [print ansible_facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [DEV1] => {
    "ansible_facts[\"kernel\"]": "4.9.0-12-amd64"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
DEV1                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I am printing the OS kernel in the output screen. To print the complete ansible_facts, use below playbook:

```
- name: Play to get the gather facts content   
  hosts: DEV1   
  become: yes   
  become_user: testuser   
  tasks:
  - name: print ansible_facts
    debug:
     var: ansible_facts
```